# Do I need to declare a constructor and destructor in a new class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am noticing a lot in my data structures class that they are declaring constructors and destructors. This is for C++ by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: This is duplicate:
[Should i define the default constructor? \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184060/should-i-define-the-default-constructor)

Comment: The answer is going to depend on what state you expect your class-objects to be in after they are constructed.  If you are okay with the default behavior that you get without a constructor, then there's no need to write a constructor; OTOH if you need to specify on-construction behavior explicitly, writing a constructor is the way to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should i define the default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184060/should-i-define-the-default-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these objects allocate and retain memory? Do they allocate resources that must be released?

If so, yes, a destructor is required. If not, no.

This is all part of understanding [C++ RIAA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) which is the defining methodology here.

Constructors aren't necessary for `struct`, those are often treated as "dumb data" with no built-in smarts, but they are *usually* necessary for `class` as you're going to be calling `new` on those with an expectation that the data is properly initialized, not zeroed.