# Are constructors specified with the default keyword trivial?

Tags: c++, constructor, default

I know that among other things, a trivial constructor has to be implicitly defined.

Does this also apply when we use the default keyword?

Say we specify a T()=default constructor , is it considered user-provided or is it treated like an implicit constructor?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502828/c-default-keyword-classes-not-switch

Comment: Man I have no idea what your asking, rethink your question and rewrite it.

Comment: It depends. See [trivial default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor).

Comment: Does this question really deserve so many downvotes?

Comment: yes, explicitly defaulted is considered trivial.

Comment: @sp2danny no, see the link above. It *can* be trivial.

Comment: "Does this also apply when we use the default keyword" was referring to needing the constructor to be implicit. I was not sure if using the default keyword counted as a user-provided constructor or not. My wording on the last line was just not good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a user-declared constructor that is defaulted on its first declaration may be trivial:

```
struct Foo
{ 
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int, int);

    char x;
};

#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_trivially_constructible<Foo>::value, "Works");
```

The example demonstrates how to define a POD class even in the presence of user-defined (non-default) constructors.

From the standard (12.1), "a default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided" (plus conditions), and (8.4.2):

> A function is *user-provided* if it is user-declared and not explicitly defaulted or
>   deleted on its first declaration.

However, note that triviality of a default constructor depends on more than just its declaration and definition. To expand the quote from 12.1:

> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> — its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
>
> — no non-static data member of its class has a brace-or-equal-initializer, and
>
> — all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
>
> — for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default constructor.

Comment: The standard quote about user provided constructors is exactly what I was looking for. I am aware of the other requirements but thanks for the efford. I guess I really should had worded the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit constructor is one provided by the compiler if you don't define one. That's a default constructor having no argument, unless you would like to have your own constructor with or without arguments to precisely control initialization of your object instance data members.