# Qt5: How to get rid of the compiler warnings for this Singleton?

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am using Qt5 on a Windows 7 platform.
I've implemented a Singleton for a database I work with.
So far it's ok, it works fine, but when I compile the code I always get 2 warnings related to copy constructor and to assignment operator.

**Here is the code:**

```
class DataBase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static DataBase * instance(QObject * parent = 0);
    static void destroy();
    //
    QString openDataBaseConnection();
    void closeDataBaseConnection(QString & connectionName);

private:
    DataBase(QObject * parent);
    ~DataBase();
    DataBase(DataBase const &){} // <- copy constructor
    DataBase & operator = (DataBase const &){} // <- assignment operator
    static DataBase * pInstance;
};
```

**And here are the compiler warnings:**

> 1) Base class QObject should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor
>   2) No return statement in function returning non-void (that's for the assignment operator code line).

Well, what can I do in order to finally get rid of these 2 warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to initialize `QObject` base with the same parent as `other` has:

   ```
   DataBase(DataBase const& other) :
   QObject(other.parent())
   // copy-construct members
   {
   }
   ```
2. The `operator=` should look like:

   ```
   DataBase &operator=(DataBase const& other)
   {
       QObject::operator=(other);
       // copy-assign members
       return *this;
   }
   ```

   The warning is about that [you forgot to `return *this;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference).

Note that what you're doing are not default implementations. They do nothing!

You'll probably want to use [`default`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502828/what-does-default-mean-after-a-class-function-declaration) keyword (if you're compiling under C++11 or later) to leave the implementation of these function up to the compiler:

```
DataBase(DataBase const &) = default;
DataBase &operator=(DataBase const&) = default;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not the default implementation. They do nothing"? Please elaborate a little bit, I am beginner in C++ ...

Comment: When you're defining the special member functions yourself, you have to implement what you want them to do manually (copying, `return`ing `*this;`).

Comment: 1, Yes, no more warning on copy constructor.  And 2: stupid me, I forgot to return something there... Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: No problem... I added `CONFIG += c++11` in the .pro  file and now it compiles like a charm! :)

Comment: I suppose this will work for me too: `DataBase(DataBase const &) = delete;` and `DataBase &operator=(DataBase const&) = delete;`

Comment: Of course, if you don't need to copy the class, or you want to prevent yourself from doing so (the copy might be expensive or just a wrong thing to do).