# What is "View() = default" in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

It's a syntax I've never seen in C++.

See the following:

```
class View
{
    private:
    int screenSize;
    int screenScale; //"the ZOOM"
    Point origin;
public:
    const int minScreenSize = 6;
    const int maxScreenSize = 30;

    View():screenSize(25),screenScale(2),origin(-10,-10){}
    ~View() = default;
    View(const View&) = default;
    View(View&&) = default;
    View& operator=(const View&) = default;
    View& operator=(View&&) = default;
    View& myAdd() = delete;
}
```

What is the meaning of:

`View() = default` and `View() = delete`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Constructor() = default;` 
means that you explicitly want the compiler to generate the default constructor for that class


`Constructor() = delete;` 
means that you explicitly forbid the usage of that constructor.

Comment: see here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502828/what-does-default-mean-after-a-class-function-declaration, please make a quick search on Google before posting!

Answer (score 0):

It tells the compiler to generate a default "default constructor" for your class.

This was introduced in C++11.

The counterpart is `= delete;` which would instruct the compiæer to *not* generate the function.

`= default;` is preferable to an empty user defined consteuctor `{}` since used defined destructors are never `trivial` by definition (even when they are empty), but the compiler generated function is.

More detail here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor