# What does the "&" that precedes the "=" in the assignment operator declarations do

Tags: c++, c++11

I was going through an question [What does “default” mean after a class' function declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502828/what-does-default-mean-after-a-class-function-declaration) and operator declarations like

```
  C& operator=(const C&) & = default;
  C& operator=(C&&) & = default;
```

I wanted to know what does the "&" that precedes the "=" in the assignment operator declarations do?

Comment: it specifies that the membre fonction can only be called on a l-value reference of this class

Comment: So is `C& operator=(const C&) && = default;` this valid for a r-value reference call?

Comment: yes, you can also spécifie them to be const

Comment: @Tyker Not _on lvalue references_ but on _lvalues_ of this class (objects of type `C` with category lvalue). You can write `C c; c = ...` and there are no references involved.

Comment: @DanielLangr yes i you are right my wording wasn't great