# C++: default constructor with initialized lists

Tags: c++, default-constructor

So, I'm asking this question about constructors, but it applies to all member methods that a compiler provides to a class.

I'm a little confused about the `default` keyword. What are the restrictions, what are the limitations (only Ctor with no parameters? Only one default?)
and more specifically:

- Is the only way to use it (for class A) is:

```
    A() = default;
```

- Is it possible to define a constructor, that has an initializer list, as "default"?
- Is there any virtue to such a constructor? and if there is, what is the proper syntax to do it?
- Can I also define (and not only declare) a constructor and make it default?

  ```
    class A
    {
    public:
        A() = delete;
        A(int val) : x(val) {} // how to make it default?;
    private:
        int x;
    };

    int main()
    {
        A a(2);
    }
  ```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how to connect the constructor argument `val` with the member `x`, so it's not possible to make such a constructor.

Comment: Default constructor is a special term meaning a constructor called when program has to create an object, but there are no additional parameters (it can happen explicitly by doing e.g. `A a;`, or implicitly, when you do e.g. `vector<A> v(10)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502828/what-does-default-mean-after-a-class-function-declaration

Comment: Specifying a "default" constructor means, literally "initialize everything in the class using whatever default applies to it". Specifying and initializer list means that something gets initialized to something other than whatever its default is. Therefore it cannot be a default constructor. The End.

Comment: `default` is not a mechanism for saying that a particular contructor should be the default constructor  Instead its a way of specifying for certain kinds of constructor that you want the default implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only one default?

Yes. Try making two default constructors:

```
      A() = delete;
      A(int val = 10) : x(val) {}
```

And it will immediately result in an error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘A()’ is ambiguous
```

> Is the only way to use it (for class A) is:
> `A() = default;`

The definition from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

> **A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or with default arguments provided for every parameter).**

So, the answer is no, you can write a default constructor with multiple default parameters, but it should be callable as `A()` in any context i.e., you should be able to write `A object;` with any of the constructors below. All of the following are valid default constructors:

```
A() = default;
A(int x = 10) {}
A(int x = 10, int y = 10) {}
A(std::initializer_list<T> list = {}) {}

A object; // will work with any of the constructors above
```

Of course you can use only one of them for a class.

> Is there any virtue to such a constructor?

It depends on your needs, your application, your design, whatever. The choice is with you. But personally I wouldn't make a default constructor that takes an `initializer_list` or multiple default arguments just because it adds to the confusion. One important point to keep in mind here is that, in my opinion, the default constructor should be very light and ideally should just be an empty function call. The reason for this is that you often end up using your class in a container and this could result in a lot of default constructor calls. If your default constructor is doing a lot of things, then you will pay a performance penalty. Consider:

```
std::vector<A> vec(1000); // results in 1000 calls to default constructor of A
```

> Can I also declare (and not only define) a constructor and make it default?

No. If you don't provide a definition for a constructor or any function, it will result in an error which usually goes like `undefined reference to xxx`. You can still write `=default` which is close to what you want.

Also note that following two default constructors [are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor):

```
A() = default; //1
A() {} //2
```

- `1` is a trivial default constructor. You are explicitly telling the compiler to generate a trivial default constructor.
- `2` is non-trivial user defined constructor.

Comment: I tried to compile one of the options you suggested: `A(int x = 10) = default;` and I got "invalid type for defaulted constructor" 
I guess what you mean was that I cannot use the "default" keyword with other options but only with the `A() = default` one.

Comment: Correct. The default keyword can be used with `A() = default` only because the compiler doesn't know how to connect the constructor argument `x` with some data member.