# Returning local variable from a function in c++?

Tags: c++, function

This is excerpted from [one of the c++ tutorials](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/):

```
// vectors: overloading operators example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};
    CVector (int,int);
    CVector operator + (CVector);
};

CVector::CVector (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}

CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param) {
  CVector temp;
  temp.x = x + param.x;
  temp.y = y + param.y;
  return (temp);
}

int main () {
  CVector a (3,1);
  CVector b (1,2);
  CVector c;
  c = a + b;
  cout << c.x << "," << c.y;
  return 0;
}
```

In the operator overloading function, it creates a local var `temp` then returns it, I am quite confused, is this the right way?

Comment: We could give a more meaningful answer than "yes" if you explain what you're confused about.

Comment: If you don't count the fact that `operator+` is typically implemented in terms of `operator+=`.

Comment: Are the parentheses in `return (temp)` necessary?

Comment: @qed No, they are unnecessary noise.

Answer (score 5):

*"is this the right way?"*

***Yes it is.*** Note that it is not local variable, but *a copy* of local variable that is actually returned, which is perfectly valid and right thing to do. Be cautious about returning local variables while returning by pointer or reference, not while ***returning by value***.

Comment: Perhaps such operation can cause undefined behavior. For instance, if class stores a pointer to some string which is allocated in constructor and if it has only default copy constructor.

Comment: @Michael: That is however not this case and quite unrelated to this matter.

Comment: Ok. Then using class described by the following link will be alright here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278625/when-do-we-have-to-use-copy-constructors ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it's returned by value. Had the function had the signature that follows, it would not have been correct:

```
CVector& CVector::operator+(CVector param);
```

By the way, a more efficient implementation would look like:

```
CVector CVector::operator+(const CVector &param) const;
```

Comment: In short, pass by reference, return by value.