# difference between Student& a, Student &a;

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I am confused about these terms.

Let suppose we have a class of Student then what will be the meaning of

```
class Student{
   public:
     Student(const Student& a){ ... }
     Student(const Student &a){ ... }
};
```

I want to ask the meaning of the following terms

```
Student& a;
Student &a;
```

These are used for copy constructors.
The thing I know they are mostly used for deep and shallow copy constructor.

Comment: Absolutely no difference at all. Just taste of the author.

Comment: There is no difference besides readbility.

Comment: ok no difference but are the meaning of both?

Comment: @UmarAsghar The argument named `a` is a [*reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) to a `const Student`. That is, it refers to a `Student` object that is declared somewhere else, and cannot modify it. Another [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/611-references/).

Comment: Isn't this one of those new, experimental C++0x features - one is an lvalue and the other an rvalue reference?

Comment: @KerrekSB No, that would be `Student&` and `Student&&`

Comment: @BoBTFish: What about `Student and` & `Student&`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Upsettingly, that is guaranteed to work. As is `compl Student` for declaring a destructor. (Are you a bit bored this morning?)

Comment: @BoBTFish: Waiting for the build...

Answer (score 1):

```
int   i   =   5;
^^^   ~       =
Type  Name  Value
(int) (i)    (5)


int&   ref   =  i;
^^^^^  ~~~      =
Type   Name   Value
(int&) (ref)   (i)


int  & ref   =  i;
^^^^^^ ~~~      =
Type   Name   Value
(int&) (ref)   (i)


int   &ref   =  i;
^^^^^^^~~~      =
 Type  Name   Value
(int&) (ref)   (i)
```

So basically these two:

```
Student& a;
Student &a;
```

are more or less the same thing.

As for what is the purpose of a copy constructor check out:

- [When do we have to use copy constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3278625/1147772)
- [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2685854/1147772)
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Comment: Did you really mean to initialize a reference to int with `nullptr`?  I am surprised that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

When I was starting to learn C, I was confused about pointer syntax. `char* c;`, `char * c;` and `char *c;` seemed different to me and I was terrified with so many types in C.

But it turned out that you can put an asterisk anywhere in between the *'main'* type name (e.g `int`, `char`, or even a pointer, etc) and the variable name. That means, all these declarations are the same.

This also applies to references in C++. Actually, it depends of the developer's coding style while the meaning doesn't change.